# preserve bash return code through eval and function

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash function, `hle` (highlight errors), that highlights important text when building.   It is implemented as follows:

```
hle() (
  set -o pipefail
  "$@" 2>&1 |
  sed -f $hldir/red.sed -f $hldir/blue.sed -f $hldir/orange.sed
)
```

so you could run `hle make target`, and all errors would appear to be red, warnings orange, and debug would be blue

Now, I have a script that does something like this:

foo.sh:

```
eval hle $command
[ $? ] && echo "SUCCESS"
```

But this doesn't work as `$?` represents the return code of the eval (which I believe is the return code of hle itself...)   How would I preserve the return code from `$command` in my script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you found out, your implementation of `hle` should already result int the correct exit code. However, the test `[ $? ]` is flawed. With `[ $? = 0 ]` it should work as expected.

Nevertheless, here is an alternative implementation of `hle` that doesn't require changing `set -o` options and therefore doesn't need a sub shell too:

```
hle() {
  "$@" 2>&1 |
  sed -f "$hldir/red.sed" -f "$hldir/blue.sed" -f "$hldir/orange.sed"
  return "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
}
```

For `eval`, the exit status is that of the evaluated command, see [bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html):

> `eval [arguments]`
> The arguments are concatenated together into a single command, which is then read and executed, and its exit status returned as the exit status of eval

**By the way:** Depending on `$command` you don't need `eval` at all. Right know I can only think of one case where `eval` would be important, namely pipes (`command="cmd1 | cmd2"`). However, in such a pipe only the first command would be executed by `hle`. If you really need the `eval` then put it inside the function (`{ eval "$@"; } 2>&1 |`).

Comment: This seems to work:  `eval hle false; echo $?; eval hle true; echo $?` gives `1` `0`

Comment: I just discovered, that my original solution also passes the above test -- the issue was with `[ $? ] &&` -- this treats `$?` as true if it is either `0` or `1`....   Sigh...

Comment: `eval hle false; [ $? ] && echo true` echos `true`, but `eval hle false; [ $? == 0 ] && echo true` works properly

Comment: @HardcoreHenry \*facepalm\* Thank you for letting me know. I already wondered why `pipefail` didn't work for you but never thought about the `[ $? ]` part. I added your findings to this answer to make it complete.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, so after my conversatio nwith @Socowi, I discovered the problem wasn't with the eval or function, but rather with my test.

In the script, the return value of `eval hle $command` is in fact the same as the return value from `command`.   My problem was with the `[ $? ] && echo SUCCESS`...   `$?` resolves to either `1` or `0`, which is always considered true within `test`.   The proper line should have been:

```
eval hle $command
[ $? == 0 ] && echo "SUCCESS"
```

Comment: Try to make use of `[[ $? -ne 0 ]] || echo "SUCCESS"` instead. The exit status of that line will be 0, which comes in handy if you want to use the code in a Makefile or `set -e` is set.